# How to handle errors while setting the name server with Net::DNS

Tags: perl, dns

I am setting the name server used by the resolver with `Net::DNS`

```
my $resolver = Net::DNS::Resolver->new();
$resolver->nameservers( $somenameserver );
```

If the argument is wrong, an error is printed on standard error. E.g.,

```
unresolvable name: uuu.aaa.eee at check_rbl line 145.
```

and the functions returns 0, if everything is OK then 1 is returned.

So far, so good.

I would like to suppress the error message on standard error and perform a custom action.

How can I avoid the automatic error message? And how I get the error message?

Comment: Resolve `$somenameserver` to an IP address

Comment: @ikegami Would work. I thought that other errors would also be caught, but it appears that it only checks if it resolves to an IP address. Giving a random existing IP address, which does not respond to DNS queries, just times out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Capture::Tiny` for this.

Btw `->nameservers()` returns all valid nameservers in a list context. If all nameservers passed are invalid, it returns an empty list.

If you change `@servers` to a scalar value `$server` you get an `undef`.

```perl
use Net::DNS::Resolver;
use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);

my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new();

my ($stdout, $stderr, @servers) = capture {
    $res->nameservers("8.8.8.8a");
};

if ( @servers == 0 ) {
    printf "Error found: %s\n", $stderr;
}
else {
    print "Everything fine.\n";
}
```